# Why we don't use <h> for hyperlink instead of <a> for anchor?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I searched a lot about this subject on the Internet but couldn't find anything. Why we use `<a>` tag for a link to other pages? A stands for anchor and in my opinion, it doesn't describe hyperlink. Is there any philosophy behind the scene? I think `<h>` (hyperlink) is more related to the purpose of the tag.

Comment: There's no `<h>` tag in HTML. Where did you get it?

Comment: I know. I want to know why they chose <a> tag over something more related like <h>!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` element can link to either another document, or another `a` element in the same document. The target `a` element is itself usually not a hyperlink, but a named anchor (`<a name="example">`). But it can be both, as stated by none other than the HTML 1.0 IETF draft (though this statement does not appear in HTML 2.0).

So the `a` element serves a dual purpose: as a hyperlink, and as a document anchor.

Why create a single element with a dual purpose? Because there really isn't a need to have two separate elements for the same concept of a hyperlink (or, more precisely, a hypertext link).

Note that the `a` element is not to be confused with the `link` element, which is a document metadata element that appears in the head, not as part of the document content in the body.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of `<a>` is to be an anchor. We specify the hyperlink by using href which stands for "Hypertext REFerence". If we used `<h>` as you suggested, we would have to specify the links directly. With `<a>` tag, we can have a text but the link could be different. For example "Go to google": google could just be a text whose link "www.google.com" could be put in the href attribute of anchor tag.

Whereas if we had `<h>` we would have to show "Go to www.google.com". I think this looks ugly. If the link is longer, imagine how bad it could look!

Comment: Thanks it looks reasonable.

Comment: Can you mark it as accepted answer?